# Retrieving Polymorphic Hibernate Objects Using a Criteria Query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, polymorphism, criteria, detachedcriteria

In my model I have an abstract "User" class, and multiple subclasses such as Applicant, HiringManager, and Interviewer. They are in a single table, and I have a single DAO to manage them all.

User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="User")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(
    name="role",
    discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING
)
public abstract class User extends BaseObject implements Identifiable<Long> ...
```

HiringManager (for example):

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("HIRING_MANAGER")
public class HiringManager extends User ...
```

Now if I wanted to, say, get all the hiring managers that are not associated with a department, how would I do that? I imagine it would look something like:

```
DetachedCriteria c = DetachedCriteria.forClass(User.class);
c.add(Restrictions.eq("role", "HIRING_MANAGER"));
c.add(Restrictions.isNull("department"));
List<User> results = getHibernateTemplate().findByCriteria(c);
```

But when I run this, Hibernate complains "could not resolve property: role" (Which actually makes sense because the User class really doesn't have an explicit role property)
So what's the right way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I may be missing something obvious but since you want to find hiring managers, why don't you just pass the `HiringManager` subclass as the class to the `Criteria`?

Just in case, there is a special `class` property that you can use to restrict a query to a subtype. From the Hibernate reference documentation:

> #### [14.9. The where clause](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-where)
>
> ...
>
> The special property `class` accesses
>   the discriminator value of an instance
>   in the case of polymorphic
>   persistence. A Java class name
>   embedded in the where clause will be
>   translated to its discriminator value.
>
> ```
> from Cat cat where cat.class = DomesticCat
> ```

You can use this special class property with the Criteria API too, but with a minor change:  you have to use the *discriminator value* as value.

```
c.add(Restrictions.eq("class", "HIRING_MANAGER"));
```

Unlike with HQL, it looks like Hibernate is not doing the translation with the Criteria API. I don't really like the idea of using the discriminator value in the code and there is maybe another cleaner way but I'm not aware of it. But it works.

Comment: And you can use the value of HiringManager.class in the query as well as the value of the discriminator; so it can be written as: c.add(Restrictions.eq("class", HiringManager.class));

Comment: In HQL you use it like `alias.class = HiringManager` without `.class` suffix.

Comment: @Pascal Thivent  How can I order by class in this case. 
.(.(.("")));
.(.(.().(.(.("")), .("")).(.(""))));

then i got error Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [class] on this ManagedType

Answer (score 3):

Note that this also works for Joined Subclass inheritance mappings, with one caveat.  The class used in the Restriction must be a concrete class.  If you have a model like Animal <- Mammal <- Cat, you cannot do `Restrictions.eq("class", Mammal.class);` and expect to get back all Mammals.  Instead, I had to brute force it using Restrictions.or with all known concrete classes (using Restrictions.in() gave a class cast exception when executing the query).